# How to check if a Firestore Document reference exist in a javascript array of Document references?

Tags: javascript, arrays, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a document with an array as it's field which basically stores references to other documents.

When I fetched the document data and checked if a document reference is in the array, I always get a result that it doesn't exist in the array, even if its already in there.

```
//The below codes logs as 'false'

console.log([db.doc('collectionName/docId')].includes(db.doc('collectionName/docId')))

console.log(db.doc('collectionName/docId') === db.doc('collectionName/docId'))
```

I think there is something unique with each document reference.
If this is the case then how can I check if a document reference exists in an array of document references?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I learnt it the hard way that JS objects are compared by references and not by their contents . Since the document reference objects are not equal, the only way I could do it was to compare the id of the document objects, to see if they match.

This returns **true**:

```
console.log([db.doc('/collectionName/docId')]
.some(doc => doc.id === db.doc('/collectionName/docId').id));
```